# Input Strings into String Arrays(Dynamic)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So I have two string arrays, one for my friends, the other for their numbers. I go to my combo box (displays list of names) I click on it and it displays their number on a label. My problem is I want the user to a enter a new name and number in 2 textboxes, then transfer the name on the combo box. Once their name is in the box, I click on it and it display's their number on label. Is there a way to transfer the new items onto my arrays?

```
Option Explicit On
Module MainModule
Public strPeople() As String = {"Kyle", "John", "Jake", "Donna", "Carly", "Ty", "Mavis"}
Public strPhoneNumbers() As String = {"945-1232", "804-2329", "290-7321", "928-4569", "205-9893", "320-0195", "305-4520"}
Public tempList As New List(Of String)
End Module
```

Here Is My Main Form

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(strPeople)
End Sub

Private Sub AboutToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AboutToolStripMenuItem1.Click
    AboutBox1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim strPhoneNums As String = strPhoneNumbers(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
    Label3.Text = "Phone Number: " & strPhoneNums
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    //Add Contact Button
    If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
        ReDim Preserve strPeople(7)
        strPeople(7) = TextBox1.Text
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(strPeople(7))
    End If
    If TextBox2.Text <> "" Then
        ReDim Preserve strPhoneNumbers(7)
        strPhoneNumbers(7) = TextBox2.Text
    End If
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just work with lists?

Comment: Are you using concurrent arrays rather than a single array or collection of objects with multiple properties for a specific reason?  If not then don't.  That's something that is sometimes insisted upon during the early stages of a course but not something any serious (or even not so serious) developer would do in real code once they know there's a better alternative.

Comment: I am using 2 different arrays, One for Name, Other For Numbers. So when a name  is typed onto my textbox1 and number is typed onto textbox1,  I want to resize the 2 arrays for every time the user enters new contacts. I'm begging you, is there a way to do that.

Comment: @JerrySmith, you want addfeatures of `List` to the array. Why you cannot use type `List(Of String)` which already contains behavior you need?

Comment: Use an own `Person` class with properties `Name` and `Number`. Also don´t use an array but a generic collection type (List, Dictionary, ...). This will save you alot of pain in the future when you enhance your app.